# What is a Generalized Feedforward Neural Network (GFF)?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I came across with the term GFF in some research paper. I found a line on GFF at https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Systematic-Trajectory-Search-Algorithm-for-the-Chen-Tseng/5c01686a41c31a6b7a9077edb323ed88cf158a98 that says "...links are not restricted to just going from one layer to the next layer". Is it that a part of the links of one layer can skip the next layer and fed to another non-adjacent layer? If so, then what will the links of the adjacent layer do? Can anybody throw a light on this type of network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting confused.  The illustrations in figure 1 clarify it quite easily for me.  Yes, a link can go from any layer to any higher layer; links are not restricted to the next layer up.  Note how node 1 in the input layer drives the hidden node in each of three layers, as well as the output layer.  [I'll stick with node 1; the four input nodes are topologically identical.]

I'm not sure where you're confused with "the links of the adjacent layer".  From your usage, I gather that you term a link owned by the layer of its source node.  For example, the link from node 5 to node 8 "belongs" to the first (lowest) hidden layer, not to the output layer.

With that usage, let's look at a particular case in point: the link from node 1 to node 6 (middle hidden layer), skipping the lowest hidden layer (consisting of node 5).  For sake of illustration, let's ignore the other links from node 1.  Now, node 1 is driving *only* node 6, driving it directly from the input layer.  This skip does not affect the other links at all: they continue to do what they do: drive the value of the source node into the linear equation of the destination node.  Node 5 continues to be a function of the other input nodes; Node 5 continues to drive nodes 6, 7, and 8.

Perhaps your worries can be eased with a "dummy" node in each layer that gets skipped.  Again, let's focus on the links from node 1 (to nodes 5, 6, 7, 8).  Instead of letting node 1 skip layers, let's add nodes 1.2, 1.3, and 1.4 in the low, middle, and high hidden layers.  Replace the "skipper" links from node 1.  Instead, use these links, top (output) to bottom (input)

```
1.4 -> 8
1.3 -> 1.4
1.3 -> 7
1.2 -> 1.3
1.2 -> 6
1   -> 1.2
1   -> 5
```

In the sequence 1 -> 1.2 -> 1.3 -> 1.4, all link (edge) weights are 1 with a bias of 0.  You now have a topology with identical algebraic properties, and no link skips a layer.

Note that *any* finite, acyclic network is a GFF.  "Layer" is a convenience for our design; the topology restricts the "layer" of a node only by its longest path from an input node, and its longest path to an output node.  It helps us to organize the nodes into layers for our own purposes, timing, debugging, etc., but a generalized flow simulator doesn't care.  All it cares about is which nodes drive which other nodes, and whether a given node has all the inputs it needs to drive its output links on the next computational cycle.

Does that help?

Comment: Please display the figure 1

Comment: That's figure 1 in the link you supplied.

Comment: "Note that any finite, acyclic network is a GFF." - this very statement of yours explains everything. I'm sorry about questioning about the Figure 1 that was present in my question itself. Thanks a lot dear.

Comment: That's excellent to hear.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.